# vba Vlookup across workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I seem to have an error in the below syntax line.  I believe the issue lies with range parameter of workbook book1. I cannot figure out why. Basically I'm tring to vlookup across 2 workbooks.

The code is invoked from workbook - book1. Just before this line of code workbook - book2 is activated. Both the workbooks are  open. I captured the error code 2015 by replacing the left side with a variant variable.

I appreciate any help with this vlookup issue. Thanks.

```
 Cells(j, c + 2).value = [VLookup(workbooks(book2).sheets(5).range(Cells(j, c + 1)), workbooks(book1).sheets(4).range(cells(row1+2,1),cells(row2,col1)), 3, false)]
```

Comment: Are book1 and book2 workbook variables? If so, the "Cells" within "Range(...)" should also be qualified by 2workbooks(book2).sheets(5)." etc.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: The exact error when using the above piece of code is shown in cell as #VALUE!. When replacing cells(j,c+2.value with variant variable (test), the value of test is error 2015.

Comment: Thanks, resolved the issue with all help from all and replaceing _[Vlookup]_ with _Application.Vloopup_..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've provided only a snippet of code, but first things first let's make sure you have all the variables defined. I have also added a few more to simplify and possibly help trap errors.

```
Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooks()
Dim lookFor as String
Dim srchRange as Range
Dim book1 as Workbook
Dim book2 as Workbook

'Set some Workbook variables:
Set book1 = Workbooks("Book 1 Name") '<edit as needed
Set book2 = Workbooks("Book 2 Name") '<edit as needed

'Set a string variable that we will search for:
lookFor = book2.sheets(5).range(Cells(j, c + 1))

'Define the range to be searched in Book1.Sheets(4):
Set srchRange = book1.Sheets(4).Range(cells(row1+2,1).Address, cells(row2,col1).Address)

'This assumes that the Book2 is Open and you are on the desired active worksheet:
ActiveSheet.Cells(j, c + 2).value = _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookFor, _
         book1.Sheets(4).Range(srchRange.Address), 3, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had tested your code with some modification. I replaced lookfor declaration from string to range and replaced the Vlookup portion - _"book1.Sheets(4).Range(srchRange.Address)"_ with simply srchRange. I have incorporated the same into my code, but had problem using hidden feature of VBA vlookup, see my snippet [Vlookup], which caused the problem. Worked fine, when replaced it with usual function call.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a simple example.

```
Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooks()

    Dim lookFor As Range
    Dim srchRange As Range

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook

    Dim book2Name As String
    book2Name = "test.xls"    'modify it as per your requirement

    Dim book2NamePath As String
    book2NamePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name

    Set book1 = ThisWorkbook

    If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)
    Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)


    Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)   ' value to find
    Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("B:C")    'source

    lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)

End Sub

Function IsOpen(strWkbNm As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Set wBook = Workbooks(strWkbNm)

    If wBook Is Nothing Then    'Not open
        IsOpen = False
        Set wBook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        IsOpen = True
        Set wBook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the excellent demonstration, I've successfully implemented certain features of your code into mine. As I use a lot of variables, using line - _"Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("B:C")"_ will not be useful. David's approach helped. I had also problem using hidden Vlookup feature, see my code - resulting with _#NAME?_ error. I appreciate all help provided.