# VLookUp to another Open Workbook Error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've come to have this type of error and was not able to resolve it til now. This occurs when I use the VLookUp function in VBA.

> “Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class” error

This is my complete code:

```
Dim wbSLW as Workbook
Dim wbSLWDir as String

wbSLWDir = "C\Documents\test.xlsx" 'not constant directory
set wbSLW = Workbooks.Open(wbSLWDir)

Thisworkbook.Activate
With Thisworkbook.Sheets(1)
    ' line Error
    .Range("AE2").Formula = _
        WorksheetFunction.vlookUp(.Range("I2").Value, wbSLW.FullName & "Sheet3!E:F", 2, 0) 
End With
```

Can you please help me figure it out?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658334/vba-vlookup-across-workbooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim wbSLW As Workbook
Dim wbSLWDir As String

wbSLWDir = "C\Documents\test.xlsx" 'not constant directory
Set wbSLW = Workbooks.Open(wbSLWDir)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    '''To get only the value
    .Range("AE2").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("I2").Value, wbSLW.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E:F"), 2, 0)

    '''----OR-----
    '''To insert the formula

    ''' Syntax : .Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP(Range-of-the-value-to-find" & _
                  ",'Path[FileName.xl*]SheetName'!Range-of-Array-To-Search" & _
                  ",Column-in-Array-to-output, FALSE)"

    '''With a Range reference using .Address (btw If you change 0 to 1, you'll have a $)
    .Range("AE2").Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP(" & .Range("I2").Address(0,0) & ",'" & wbSLW.Path & "\[" & wbSLW.Name & "]" & "Sheet3'!E:F, 2, FALSE)"

    '''Or directly with address of the Range
    .Range("AE2").Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP(I2,'" & wbSLW.Path & "\[" & wbSLW.Name & "]" & "Sheet3'!E:F, 2, FALSE)"
End With
```

Comment: The to get only the value works but when inserting the formula, it's not working. Thanks.

Comment: @ramedju : Is there an error in VBA or in Excel? Which error?

Comment: In Excel: `#NAME`

Comment: It errors in VBA, `Application-defined or object-defined error`.

Comment: @ramedju : This should be good now! ;) Try both and if it doesn't work, please add the formula that is printed in the cell

Comment: does workbook have a name function? i think you have to use something like dir(wbslw.fullname) or right and instrev to get the filename...

Comment: @SivaprasathV `wb.FullName` = `wb.Path` & "\" & `wb.Name`

Comment: @r3uk thanks for clearing that up... i usually use fullname property, have never used the name property.

Comment: @R3uK It works both code :) Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: @R3uK IS there any way I can replace the `Sheet3` with its specific sheetname? i.e `test`

Comment: @ramedju : Yeah, just change it directy or use `wbSLW.Name & "]" & ws.name & "'!E:F, 2, FALSE)"`

Answer (score 0):

I find when using VBA to enter a formula it helps to actually enter the formula in Excel first to confirm that it works.  If test.xlsx is open then in Sheet1 AE2 you would have

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,[test.xlsx]Sheet3!$E:$F, 2, 0)
```

If test.xlsx was closed the formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,'C:\Documents\[test.xlsx]Sheet3'!$E:$F, 2, 0)
```

As there are no double quotes within the formula you can simply copy and paste it into your code as:

```
.Range("AE2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I2, [test.xlsx]Sheet3!$E:$F, 2, 0)"
```

Now we need to change the lookup range to reference your wbSLW object:

```
.Range("AE2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I2, [" & wbSLW.Name & "]Sheet3!$E:$F, 2, 0)"
```

Note that you don't need to reference wbSLW.FullName or wbSLW.Path because test.xlsx is still open.  Excel will insert the path when you close test.xlsx.

So the full code:

```
Sub lookup()

Dim wbSLW As Workbook
Dim wbSLWDir As String

    wbSLWDir = "C\Documents\test.xlsx" 'not constant directory
    Set wbSLW = Workbooks.Open(wbSLWDir)

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range("AE2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I2,'[" & wbSLW.Name & "]Sheet3'!$E:$F, 2, 0)"
    End With
End Sub
```