# VLOOKUP across multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am basically creating a VBA script to clean out a report sheet. I have everything downpacked but cannot figure out how to make `VLOOKUP` work to check on multiple workbooks. I basically have to match serial numbers on the report to serial numbers located either on folder A or Folder B.

As of right now, I have manually set the `Range().Value =VLOOKUP` for only one workbook but If I do it for a second then it might create conflicts. However, I want to know if it's possible to `VLOOKUP` an entire column from the `LastRow` up and ignore blanks while checking both workbooks.

```
Sub LowTonerSOC()
Dim i As Long


For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "J") <> "Yes" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "K") <> "Yes" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "O") <> "Headquarters" And Cells(i, "O") <> "INDUSTRIAL" And Cells(i, "O") <> "VAUSA" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete

Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "", "999", xlWhole

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "D").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "E").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "F").Value2 >= 10 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "D").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "E").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "F").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "999", "", xlWhole

ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"

Range("G1").Value = "Physical Location"
Range("G2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G3").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B3,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G4").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B4,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G5").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B5,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G6").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B6,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G7").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B7,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G8").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B8,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G9").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B9,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G10").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B10,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G11").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B11,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G12").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B12,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G13").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B13,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G14").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B14,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G15").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B15,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G16").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B16,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G17").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B17,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G18").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B18,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G19").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B19,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G20").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B20,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G21").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B21,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G22").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B22,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G23").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B23,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G24").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B24,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G25").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B25,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G26").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B26,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G27").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B27,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G28").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B28,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G29").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B29,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"
Range("G30").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B30,'\\spwsrf\Deskside\Desktop\EUS\AssestInventory\Printers\[Printers.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$1:$G$230,2,0)"


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just loop over all workbooks and apply VLOOKUP on each.

Answer (score 0):

Pick column that has no blank in setting last row to vlookup in entire column

```
LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row, 9)
```

then for vlookup that has multiple workbook, set your workbooks

```
Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooks()
Dim lookFor as String
Dim srchRange as Range
Dim book1 as Workbook
Dim book2 as Workbook

'Set some Workbook variables:
Set book1 = Workbooks("Book 1 Name") '<edit as needed
Set book2 = Workbooks("Book 2 Name") '<edit as needed

'Set a string variable that we will search for:
lookFor = book2.sheets(5).range(Cells(j, c + 1))

'Define the range to be searched in Book1.Sheets(4):
Set srchRange = book1.Sheets(4).Range(cells(row1+2,1).Address, cells(row2,col1).Address)

'This assumes that the Book2 is Open and you are on the desired active worksheet:
ActiveSheet.Cells(j, c + 2).value = _
     Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookFor, _
     book1.Sheets(4).Range(srchRange.Address), 3, False)

End Sub
```

refer to this link for vlookup with multiple vlookup [Sub VlookupMultipleWorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658334/vba-vlookup-across-workbooks)